# Dynamically generated bash menu

Tags: bash, dynamic, menu, selection

I'm trying to generate a dynamic menu and then select the option that I want to save in a variable. So far I have this, but I'm stuck.
It somehow always defaults to

> "ERROR Selection not in list, rerun the script."

```
IFACES=$(nmcli -t -f SSID dev wifi list | grep i)
SELECTION=1
while read -r line; do
    echo "$SELECTION) $line"
    ((SELECTION++))
done <<< "$IFACES"
((SELECTION--))
echo
printf 'Select an interface from the above list: '
read -r OPT
if [[ `seq 1 $SELECTION` = $OPT ]]; then
    sed -n "${OPT}p" <<< "$IFACES" 
    IFACE=$(sed -n "${OPT}p" <<< "$IFACES") #set interface
else
    echo "ERROR Selection not in list, rerun the script."
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: What do you think `seq 1 $SELECTION` does

Comment: It prints a sequence of numbers no greater than $SELECTION.

Comment: Right so how could "$OPT" (a specific number) ever be equal to "1 2 3 4 5 ..."?

Comment: I get it now. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know the command `select` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
mapfile -t ifaces < <(printf 'foo\nbar code\nstuff\nnonsense\n')
for i in "${!ifaces[@]}"; do
    printf "%s) %s\n" "$i" "${ifaces[$i]}"
done
printf 'Select an interface from the above list: '
IFS= read -r opt
if [[ $opt =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && (( (opt >= 0) && (opt <= "${#ifaces[@]}") )); then
    printf 'good\n'
else
    printf 'bad\n'
fi
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh
0) foo
1) bar code
2) stuff
3) nonsense
Select an interface from the above list: d
bad

$ ./tst.sh
0) foo
1) bar code
2) stuff
3) nonsense
Select an interface from the above list: 5
bad

$ ./tst.sh
0) foo
1) bar code
2) stuff
3) nonsense
Select an interface from the above list: 3
good
```

Replace the `printf` with your `nmcli ...` command.

Comment: Thank you Ed, I'm new to this.

Comment: You're welcome. You need to get some kind of foundation before starting to write shell scripts as it's **extremely** easy to get it wrong and the bugs are often insidious and consequences disastrous so try reading the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson and search the archives here for bash answers by Stephane Chazelas or Charles Duffy (there are others who provide precisely correct answers too but there's a lot of "answers" that are complete nonsense and those are my 2 go-tos).

Comment: Thanks again Ed, will do.